# When creating a WCF in vs.net, how can I run and view a web page with all the endpoints?

Tags: c#, wcf

When I hit f5 it doesn't fire up my web browser with the end points exposed.

How do I get this behavoir with my service?

My web.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't.  It should run the WCF Service hosting window if you set the project up as a WCF Service project.  To view in your browser you'll need to manually browse to the address it's being hosted at.